# Rails hidden params not passing correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I am trying to pass two hidden fields and an answer to create a new answer object. Even though I can see all of the params in the hash, it seems like the hidden params aren't being included correctly with the answer. I'm sure it's just a simple thing I'm doing wrong but can't figure out where it is. Appreciate the time to look!

Params Hash:

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"VaZC2MCN0rWJnVPIqSTbPF9HvFNBfm5b5nA3H8YenuVte9SMi9Iy+G4fxz9bWhkDNwGVz9jMBVTxT/SuXFCh+A==",
 "user_id"=>"2",
 "question_id"=>"1",
 "answer"=>{"answer"=>"a"},
 "commit"=>"Create Answer"}
```

ERROR: 
SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: answers.user_id: INSERT INTO "answers" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)

_mc_answer.html.erb (Partial I am using as a form for multiple choice questions.)

This should pass the question_id and user_id along with the users' answer into the static_pages controller and create a new Answer object.

```
<h4>MC Answer:</h4>
  <p>User ID: <%= @user.id %></p>
  <p>Question ID: <%= question_id %></p>
  <%= form_for(@new_answer, url: static_pages_path(@new_answer)) do |a| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, @user.id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :question_id, question_id %>
    <%= a.text_field :answer %>
    <%= a.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @user = current_user

    if user_signed_in?  
      if @user.manager_id != nil
        @manager = @user.manager_id
      end
      @my_team = User.where("manager_id = ? AND id != ?", @manager, @user.id)
      @questions = Question.active_question.where.not(id: @user.answers)     
    end
    @new_answer = Answer.new
  end

  def new
    @new_answer = Answer.new
  end

  def create
    @user = current user ## Tried adding this to the create method per suggestion below but still getting the same issue. 
    @new_answer = Answer.new(answer_params)
    if @new_answer.save!
      flash.now[success]
    else
    end  
  end

  private


  ## Edited params from .permit(:answer => [:user_id, :question_id, :answer]) but still getting similar error.
  def answer_params
    params.require(:answer).permit(:user_id, :question_id, :answer)
  end
end
```

answer.rb model

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base


  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user

  scope :user_answered, lambda {|q| where("question_id == (?)", q) }


  def next
    Answer.where("id > ?", id).limit(1).first
  end

  def prev
    Answer.where("id < ?", id).limit(1).first
  end  
end



DB Schema for answer model if that's of any use: 

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151112025039) do

  create_table "answers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id",       null: false
    t.integer  "question_id",   null: false
    t.integer  "points_earned"
    t.text     "comment"
    t.text     "answer",        null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  end


  add_index "users", ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["unlock_token"], name: "index_users_on_unlock_token", unique: true

end
```

Comment: The full output of your server log during the problematic request might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hidden field parameters aren't going in to the parameters hash in the right spot because you used `hidden_field_tag` and didn't specify that they were to be included under the `answer` key in the hash. Try this:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "answer[user_id]", @user.id %>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried making that change by adding (@user = current_user) to the create action but still getting the same error.

Comment: The "not null constraint failed" for `answers.user_id` error?

Comment: Correct: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: answers.user_id: INSERT INTO "answers" ("answer", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?).

Comment: Where does the value go missing, then? Is @user.id OK in your view? Does it show up in the parameters hash in the server log?

Comment: Yes. In the view I have it displaying the User ID and question ID so I can make sure both were available in the partial. I included the parameters at the top. It is showing that user_id = 2 and question_id is one. The thing that seems strange is that answer=>{"answer" = "b"}. Seems like answer should either just be "b" or that the answer hash should include the user_id and question_id as well... I could be wrong though. Still a bit new to Rails so hard to know what is out of the ordinary.

Comment: @Prkl8r I made an edit to my answer. I think I found the problem.

Comment: @Prkl8r My first 'fix' didn't work, so I changed it to one that should.

Comment: OK. So I think it's getting closer... <%= a.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @user.id %> I was getting a merge error when I had it as your edit above, in searching the error it looks like it wanted that value in the formatting.

Comment: @Prkl8r Try my other thing.

Comment: I was able to do it with both formats (the "answer[user_id]" as well as the :value => ). Thanks again!!

Comment: Sweet! Sorry it took so long to spot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass each Symbol to the controller not an array of Hash.

```
  def answer_params
    params.require(:answer).permit(:answer, :user_id, :question_id)
  end
```

not

```
 def answer_params
    params.require(:answer).permit(:answer => [:user_id, :question_id, :answer])
  end
```

Because that your `"user_id"=>"2",` and `"question_id"=>"1"` are not in a sub-Hash like if it was written `"answer"=>{"answer"=>"a", "question_id"=>"1","user_id"=>"2" },`

Comment: Thanks. When I make that change, I get the following:  SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: answers.user_id: INSERT INTO "answers" ("answer", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)

Comment: With the following: Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"dYiNFA4DJjpvgZptuPi9Ka3YPx6t2ByHSMhrrrC49SETWySSB+Hf3rjMcIBoZiWHSxuJ+9zOZubWbV1VUcx70A==",
 "user_id"=>"3",
 "question_id"=>"1",
 "answer"=>{"answer"=>"a"},
 "commit"=>"Create Answer"}

Comment: :( . I edit my answer I remove an extra variable of `answer` from the `permit params` As you didn't do validation on your Model yet. Let's try a last thing `<%#= a.text_field :answer %>` Comment the answer to see if it will save the new record. You have a model call `answer` and a variable call `answer` too within the model

Comment: I made the change to the answer_parmas but still got the above error. I am confused as to why it is looking like the created_at and updated_at values aren't being created.   When I comment out the answer text_field I get a "param is missing or the value is empty: answer" Appreciate your assistance on this.

Comment: You're not defining @user in your `create` action.